# How to implement the equivalent of EOSJS in Android?

Tags: nodeos

I have the following code running. It enable eosjs functionality using http. Is there an equivalent so that I can access the testnet nodes from an Android app?

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/eosjs@15.0.3/lib/eos.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-QX0dPq5pyX33coEuy5x1UqKHFDeveQYMp7Sz+qOUwRL9mol4QDvViU+QAjd+k6P7QjPjrDCoyhK1kz2GDxCP9A=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
// Default configuration (additional options below)
config = {
  chainId: '038f4b0fc8ff18a4f0842a8f0564611f6e96e8535901dd45e43ac8691a1c4dca', // 32 byte (64 char) hex string
  keyProvider: ['5KcFCgZiixiZ69dyA5u39SGWg42NvDBD3jcyVro8drWEXrRBQtZ'], // WIF string or array of keys..
  httpEndpoint: 'http://jungle.cryptolions.io:18888',
  expireInSeconds: 60,
  broadcast: true,
  verbose: false, // API activity
  sign: true
}
eos = Eos(config)
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  See console object: Eos
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see three possibilities you could use for Android and mobile development.

---

## 1. [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/)

This one is vicarious for other JS based mobile Frameworks like [Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/) or something else. You can simply write your app and include eosjs as a normal npm module.

#### Advantage:

You can compile it for iOS as well and use all kind of other modules.

#### Disadvantage

You have to know something about web development and JS/ES/TS aswell and the library is not as mighty as pure Android.

---

## 2. Use an Android [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView)

This approach needs you to write and host a (responsive) web app that the Android WebView will use as its a source. This can also be done with React Native or other libraries that have an integrated browser feature.

#### Advantage:

Very simple to write an App with an Webview.

#### Disadvantage

Knowledge about web development (like before). Possible design/responsive/layout problems.

## 3. Write your own API Wrapper

This one will just use the [RPC calls and HTTP-Endpoints](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference). Supposing you are using Java for Android development you can just use a HTTP-Framework and wrap your functions around the REST-Interface of the endpoints. You would than do simple HTTP-POST request for [pushing transactions](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#push_transaction) or [fetching informations](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/reference#get_info).

#### Advantage:

Most flexible, because you can only include the functions that you need.

#### Disadvantage

You have to do everything on your own and rewrite functionallities. I also don't like to use HTTP in non-web frameworks.

---

#### Recommendation

Personally I would use the first approach. React Native is a very good framework designed and used by Facebook. If you are new to mobile development I would invest some time in learning React (Native). Several years ago I also used plain Java and Android for development, but this new approach really made things simple and cross platform. Also the variety of npm modules is fantastic. If you need some learning ressources just ask.

Comment: Disadvantage on 2. : only works on the main UI thread

Comment: 3. should be provided by a worker fund proposal. Ideally with scatter like support for end users.

Answer (score 0):

The eos-jvm library provides all you need for interacting with EOS from Android. https://github.com/memtrip/eos-jvm